# Why does $p(X\;|\;Y) = \displaystyle\frac{p(Z,X\;|\; Y)}{P(Z\;|\;X,Y)}$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm reading about expectation maximization and on one point in my paper it is said that:

**According to probability theory:**

$$p(X\;|\;Y) = \displaystyle\frac{p(Z,X\;|\; Y)}{P(Z\;|\;X,Y)}$$

**Where  $p$ is a density function and $P$ is a probability.**

My question is: How does one derive this?

$X$ is a set of observations, $Z$ is a set of missing data and $Y$ is a set of model parameters. In my reference $Y$ is denoted as $\theta_n$.

Thnx for any help!

Here is my reference (page 7):

http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0131478249/samplechapter/0131478249_ch03.pdf

UPDATE:

From my reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $p(Z,X\mid Y)=\dfrac{p(Z,X,Y)}{p(Y)}$ and  $p(Z\mid X, Y)=\dfrac{p(Z,X,Y)}{p(X,Y)}$ hence their ratio is $\dfrac{p(X,Y)}{p(Y)}=p(X\mid Y)$.

Comment: And now the real question: which part of this was escaping you? Note this is nothing more than copying stupidly the definitions...

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help :) I'm not sure x) Is $p$ in your notation a density function? Or a probability? :)

Comment: Were the subtleties about little-p and big-P already present in the first version of your question? Anyway, if you want a different answer, you need to be much more precise about your notations. For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, what do you call $p(X\mid Y)$?

Comment: Hi @Did, I will add my reference on the post :) In my reference $X$ is defined as set of observations and $Y$ is a set of model parameters (labeled as $\theta_n$ in my reference).

Comment: Did my comment make things any clearer? :)

Comment: The text is terrible, on the notational side... It seems that P for the distribution of Z refers to Z being discrete and p for all the others to X being continuous? Anyway, my answer stands.

Comment: +1 @Did thank you for your help! :) I appreciate the effort, and I agree with you :( The text is confusing...

Comment: You are welcome. (And, to have included the relevant portion of the text in your question is much better.)